# How to fix this error and proceed sudo gem install compass

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sass, rubygems, compass-sass

I am trying to install compass to be able to use it in sass, I have such a bug

I have updated the ruby and gems to the latest version

```
$ rvm current
ruby-2.7.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [i386-linux-gnu]
gem -v
```

3.1.3

```
   sudo gem install compass
    Building native extensions. This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing compass:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    
        current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/ext/ffi_c
    /usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201222-2810-1d9fxe6.rb extconf.rb
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
    
    You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
    environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.
    
    extconf failed, exit code 1
    
    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2 for inspection.
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.14.2/gem_make.out
```

edit:
content of file: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.14.2/gem_make.out

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.14.2/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201222-2810-1d9fxe6.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: The short answer is that you've messed up your ruby installation. You're running **two versions**: There's a system ruby installed (2.7.0) and the `rvm` version installed (2.7.2). To save yourself a lot of headache, if you're planning to use `rvm`, I would strongly recommend you completely uninstall the system ruby. You should never need to install gems as `sudo`, and running `ruby -v` should return `2.7.2`, not `2.7.0`.

Comment: You should check the content of `/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.7.0/ffi-1.14.2/gem_make.out` as the error message states, and determine what the next steps are.

Comment: @TomLord 
I tried to remove ruby and install the newest via rvm, idk how to remove it

Comment: @vgoff I pasted results in the first post, it's actually the same as you see in the console logs

Comment: Did you install the ruby development environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel as the message expects?  If so, then perhaps it is time to look to the compass resources as indicated from their homepage: http://compass-style.org

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by updating ruby ​​to the latest version. Thanks everyone for your help! :) Cheers!

```
sudo apt install ruby-full
```